# How to allow only numbers space and fraction (1 1/2) format in HTML inputbox by using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, validation, numeric, fractions

I am creating a web page where I have an input text filed in which I want to allow only numbers space and fraction like (1 1/2, 2 1/4, 4 1/2...)

Generally 1 1/2 we call as ONE AND HALF.

How can I do this using jQuery

Here is my code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sridharnetha/3o8mweu4/3/) but it is not working as expected.

```
<input id="intTextBox">
(function($) {
   $.fn.inputFilter = function(inputFilter) {
return this.on("input keydown keyup mousedown mouseup select contextmenu drop", function() {
  if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
    this.oldValue = this.value;
    this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
    this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
  } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
    this.value = this.oldValue;
    this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
  } else {
    this.value = "";
  }
});
 };
 }(jQuery));

 // Install input filters.
 $("#intTextBox").inputFilter(function(value) {
  return /^(?:(?:\d+\s)*\d+\/\d+|\d+)$/.test(value); 
  });
```

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with? Adding a [regex validation](https://html.com/attributes/input-pattern/) to an input?  Or writing a js/jquery event? In which case are you having difficulty reading the value of the input?  Checking if the current event is for a number,space or `/`? Setting the value?  Or are you just hoping someone will provide a complete solution for you?

Comment: I want to allow only numbers space and fraction Example1: 1 Example2: 1 1/2 Example3: 1/2 Example4: 2 1/4

Comment: We know what you *want* - but we don't know why you can't do it.  ie, which part of the problem are you having difficulty with?   How far did you get in your own research / attempt?

Comment: @freedomn-m I added my code in JSFiddle, updated link my questions.

Comment: Always check the browser console, your fiddle is missing jquery (select it from the drop down at the top of the javascript box) (still doesn't work, but at least you get it doing *something*)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should contain 2 parts: only number and fraction with optional number part:

```js
function test(input) {
  let pattern = /^(?:(?:\d+\s)*\d+\/\d+|\d+)$/;

  console.log(input, pattern.test(input))
}

test('1');
test('43534');
test('12/234');
test('1/2');
test('23 1/2');
test('1 1/2');
test('1.2');
test('a/b');
```